# JQuery Ajax submit button value null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery, Ajax and Struts for a web application. I am trying to submit when a button clicked. I have 4 tabs in one page. I placed 4 buttons on each tab and I want to submit the whole form when user clicked on a button through Ajax. When I submit form, I am getting values for all the form fields except button1 value as null in the form bean. Do I have any alternative to track what button clicked while submitting the whole form?  Is there any way I can pass additional parameter along with submitting whole form in ajax? Thank you!

```
$('[name=button1]').click(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/NB/AjaxSubmit.do",
        data: $('form[name=ajaxForm]').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});

<html:button property="button1"  value ="Submit"></html:button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `type` from button to `submit` ,button values are not passed with form values 
or append in the button value in the ajax url

```
  url: "/NB/AjaxSubmit.do?mybutton="+$('[name=button1]').attr('value'),
```